# Implement TouchBar functionality in Xcode Playgrounds

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground, nstouchbar

How can I implement a `NSTouchBar` in using only Xcode Playgrounds? I realize that `NSTouchBar`, and its accompanying methods including `makeTouchBar()` are contained within the `NSResponder` class, which is the superclass of `NSView`, `NSViewController`, `NSWindow`, and `SKView` (a subclass of `NSView`.)

It is for this reason that I'm a little unsure how to approach access the TouchBar. There are so many subclasses of `NSResponder` I'm unsure as to which one is the correct one. And to my knowledge I cannot even access all of them, including the `NSWindow` for the Playground, which I suspect may be the one I need to access.

My current setup is:

```
let containerView = SKView()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView
let containterScene = SKScene()
containerView.presentScene(containterScene)
```

And in checking the responder chain, for the SKView I get:

```
<SKScene> name:'(null)' frame:{{-250, -250}, {500, 500}} anchor:{0.5, 0.5}
```

And for the SKScene:

```
<SKView: 0x7fba36037a00>
<NSView: 0x7fba32d6fe80>
<PlaygroundViewBridgeService: 0x7fba32d569e0>
<NSNextStepFrame: 0x7fba32d76e20>
<NSWindow: 0x7fba32e177e0>
```

For some reason, the SKScene and SKView are not within the same chain, and I can't seem to access any responder higher than the SKView. Is there a way to extend the functionality of the already existing `NSWindow`?

Another problem is that many tutorials on using the TouchBar require access to the AppDelegate, which I don't think I have in Xcode Storyboards.

Any help implementing the TouchBar in Storyboards would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is actually quite simple. Create a custom subclass of `NSViewController` and implement the TouchBar override functions within it.

Then implement the above code:

```
let containerView = CustomSKView()
let containterScene = CustomSKScene()
containerView.presentScene(containerScene)
```

With the following additions.

```
let containerViewController = CustomNSViewController()
containerViewController.view = containerView
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerViewController.view
```

This sets your custom `NSViewController` within the responder chain, allowing it to take care of the Touch Bar. There is also no need to worry about the App Delegate.